# Google font (nunito) rendering fine on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using two google fonts in my project - lato and nunito.

Whenever I use nunito on firefox it seems to be pushed down but renders perfectly on chrome.

I have tried setting all margins to 0 and making all line heights the same but the problem still occurs.

I am using OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with Firefox: 62.0.3 and it appears like the screenshot below.

[image]

```css
#nunito {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#lato {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 id="nunito">
Hello
</h1>

<h1 id="lato">
Hello
</h1>
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, it behave the same for me .. can you add a screenshot and the version of FF you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to recreate your issue by installing nunito as a system font.

Uninstall the font locally, then restart your Firefox browser.

FYI, it may be installed via Adobe Typekit if you use it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had nunito installed through Adobe Typekit and when I removed the font I didn't have the problem anymore.